# python pandas read various dataframe from same excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Currently with pandas, I could save various dataframes (of different size) to the same excel sheet, with startrow and startcol to specify the location.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(dump_excel) as writer:
    dataframe1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=40, startcol=0)
    dataframe2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=0, startcol=0)
    dataframe3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2', startrow=0, startcol=0)
```

I would like to know, if I can read various dataframe1 and dataframe2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) of `read_excel`, you will be surprised with some of its arguments (`skiprows`, `skip_footer` and `parse_cols`).

Comment: thanks for mentioning the documentation, I have read it some times and did not find the usage I wanted. skiprow is for skipping the first rows at the beginning, skip_footer is for skipping the last rows at the end, and parse_cols is to select part of the cols. What I want would be something like parse_rows, but it did not exist.

Comment: @Jinstrong Use a combination of these three args to get the exact functionality that you want. `parse_rows` proper doesn't make sense, as it would imply that you have tables with interleaving rows.